# Scala transformations

Tags: mongodb, scala, silhouette

I am really new in Scala and I would like to ask a simple question.

I have a function that returns `Future[Option[T]`

```
def findOne(query: JsObject)(implicit reader: Reads[T]): Future[Option[T]] = {
    Logger.debug(s"Finding one: [collection=$collectionName, query=$query]")
    collection.find(query).one[T]
}
```

And I have to return `Future[Option[PasswordInfo]]`.

I tried:

```
def find(loginInfo: LoginInfo): Future[Option[PasswordInfo]] = {

    val result = find(Json.obj("loginInfo.providerID" -> loginInfo.providerID, "loginInfo.providerKey" -> loginInfo.providerKey))

    result.onSuccess{
      case something => Future.successful(Some(something).getOrElse(None))
    }
}
```

My class:

```
case class PersistentPasswordInfo(
       loginInfo: LoginInfo,
       authInfo: PasswordInfo
       ) extends TemporalModel {
  override var created: Option[DateTime] = _
  override var updated: Option[DateTime] = _
  override var _id: Option[BSONObjectID] = _
}
```

Comment: `Future.successful(Some(something).getOrElse(None))` is wrong. `Future.successful(Some(something))` should be enough, provided that something is a PasswordInfo

Comment: something is PersistentPasswordInfo and I need `authInfo` which is inside my class

Comment: `Future.successful(Some(something.authInfo))` ?

Comment: It cannot resolve .authInfo

Comment: What is T defined as on the class that contains the findOne function?

Comment: My class: `PersistentPasswordInfo`

Comment: then findOne already returns Future[Option[PasswordInfo]]

Comment: Sorry, mis-read this, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to map over the Future to get the Option, then map over the Option to get the PersistedPasswordInfo

```
def find(loginInfo: LoginInfo): Future[Option[PasswordInfo]] = {

    val result = find(Json.obj("loginInfo.providerID" -> loginInfo.providerID, "loginInfo.providerKey" -> loginInfo.providerKey))

    result.map(opt => opt.map(ppi => ppi.authInfo))
}
```

Future and Option are both Functors, they implement a method map with something like the following signature (assuming the type arg to the containing Future is A):

```
def map[B](f: A => B): Future[B]
```

so the code above changes Future by applying a function Option[PersistentPasswordInfo] => Option[PasswordInfo]

that function is created by applying map to on the contained Option with a function PersistentPasswordInfo => PasswordInfo

Comment: you could use _ to shorten this, but I wanted to show what functor was being mapped over at each step.

Shorter version would be result.map(_.map(_.authInfo))

Comment: thanks. But can u please explain it a bit? And what it will happen if `findOne` return nulls? How will `ppi.authInfo` execute? Why it would not return a null pointer exception? (Trying to access a field of an empty object)

Comment: I get `[error]  both method defaultContext in object Implicits of type => scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
[error]  and method ec in trait ContextHelper of type => scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
[error]  match expected type scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
[error]     result.map(opt => opt.map(ppi => ppi.authInfo)`

Comment: try import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global in the file that implements find. Operations that deal with Futures require an ExecutionContext, that is the default one.

Comment: Sorry mate it works. It was one of my imports. Thanks

Comment: I've tried to add some explanation of what map does to the answer, I hope that helps clear up the code.